# Pick n random records with same index from 2 different list column pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, random, apache-spark-sql

Hi I have dataframe like this:

```
cc   doc_1      doc_2

4   [a, b,..]  [1, 6,..]
9   [t, s,..]  [4, 5,..]
4   [q, f,..]  [6, 7,..]
```

I want to pick `n(1/2 of cc col)` random records from both the col `doc_1` `doc_2` with same index value. I can use `f.rand()` to pick 1 record from column but I'm not sure how I'll pick multiple records with same index from different column as well

Expected Output has randomly picked value in column

```
doc_1  doc_2
```

```
cc  doc_1                 doc_2
4   [c, f]                [5, 3]
9   [s, g,..](4 records)  [6, 5,..](4 records)
4   [r, g]                [7, 9]
```

Comment: if randomly picked `cc` value represents only one record - should it restart picking to find a (duplicated) value with multiple records ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I have to randomly pick 1/2 value of ```cc``` records from col ```doc_1 doc_2```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using standard [Collection Functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/functions.html#collection-functions):

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (4, ["a", "b", "c", "d"], [1, 6, 5, 3]),
    (9, ["t", "s", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"], [1, 6, 5, 3, 1, 6, 9, 1, 0]),
    (4, ["q", "f", "h", "j"], [1, 3, 2, 6])],
    schema=["cc", "doc_1", "doc_2"]
)

df.withColumn("nrecords", F.expr("round(cc / 2)").cast("int")) \
  .withColumn("records", F.slice(F.shuffle(F.arrays_zip("doc_1", "doc_2")), 1, F.col("nrecords"))) \
  .withColumn("records", F.map_from_entries("records")) \
  .select(
      F.map_keys("records").name("doc_1"),
      F.map_values("records").name("doc_2")) \
  .show(truncate=False)
```

```
+---------------+---------------+
|doc_1          |doc_2          |
+---------------+---------------+
|[d, c]         |[3, 5]         |
|[g, c, d, i, h]|[9, 5, 3, 0, 1]|
|[f, h]         |[3, 2]         |
+---------------+---------------+
```

The first trick is using [`arrays_zip`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_zip.html#pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_zip) to generate pairs of `(doc_1, doc_2)`. After that, we [`shuffle`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.shuffle.html#pyspark.sql.functions.shuffle)  the array and pick the first `nrecords` elements using [`slice`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.slice.html#pyspark.sql.functions.slice). Finally, we use the [`map_from_entries`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.map_from_arrays.html#pyspark.sql.functions.map_from_arrays), [`map_keys`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.map_keys.html#pyspark.sql.functions.map_keys) and [`map_values`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.map_values.html#pyspark.sql.functions.map_values) to transform the array of pairs to two different arrays.